# Lie Algebras: do we have special correspondence theorem?

Tags: lie-algebras

I've this doubt from proof in book of Humphreys Lie Algebras, chapter 2, first theorem: we have a solvable algebra $\;L\le \mathfrak g\mathfrak l(V)\;,\;\;\dim V<\infty\;$ and $\;V\neq0\;$ . Then V contains a common eigenvector for all elements in $\;L\;$ .

**Question**: I've problems in second parraph of proof: Why is it true that if I have a subspace of $\;L/[LL]\;$ **of codimension** $\;1\;$ , then its inverse image (under the canonical homomorphism, I think. It isn't said) is ideal of codimension $\;1\;$ , too?

By correspondence theorem (of rings, groups, *not the one* between Lie groups and algebras), I know index of ideal in $\;L/LL]\;$ is the same as index of inverse image of that ideal in $\;L\;$ , but I am unable to connect this with codimension.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just go through the proof of the statement about index and see that it also works for codimension (the index is not a very useful thing to consider in these cases as it will always be either infinite or $0$)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you very much, but I've some doubts: not every subspace is ideal, but I think the other way is true (right?). Now, with proof of index I take representatives in quotients, lift them to inverse image and show they are full set of representatives (this is very similar as with groups, I believe). But here: if $\;\hat T\le L/[LL]\;$ is subspace it doesn't need to be ideal (even that $\;L/[LL]\;$ abelian...or am I wrong here?), so how I lift basis of it to basis of $\;T=\pi^{-1}(\hat T)\;$ in $\;L\;$ with number of elements one less  than $\;\dim L\;$ ?

Comment: Inverse image of an ideal is an ideal (this is part of the correspondence theorem). And just go through the same argument using a basis instead of a set of coset representatives in order to see that it preserves codimensions.